# Succesfully Deployed .war file to tomcatv8.5.20 server through jenkins wont show in the browser

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, jenkins

I am rather new to AWS and tomcat,jenkins and spring boot. I am having trouble showing the deployed website in my server. when I was testing  the url would say "localhost:8181/#/dashboard" and I know when I deploy the project in tomcat the url has to be the name of the project. So for this proyect it should be "someurl/HousingManagementSystem/" but it returns a 404. In my tomcat manager html it shows that the project is running.

Here is what jenkins say when it finishes building the project(only deploy part)

```
18:51:38 Deploying /home/ec2=user/.jenkins/workspace/HousingManagementSystem/target/HousingManagementSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to container Tomcat 8.x Remote with context /HousingManagementSystem
18:51:38   Redeploying [/home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/HousingManagementSystem/target/HousingManagementSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
18:51:38   Undeploying [/home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/HousingManagementSystem/target/HousingManagementSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
18:51:39   Deploying [/home/ec2-user/.jenkins/workspace/HousingManagementSystem/target/HousingManagementSystem-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
18:51:43 Finished: SUCCESS
```

Now, this shows it is deploying and here is also catalina log:

```
31-Aug-2017 18:54:50.810 INFO [Executor #0 for master : executing 
HousingManagementSystem #18] jenkins.plugins.slack.SlackNotifier.prebuild 
Invoking Started...
31-Aug-2017 18:54:51.078 INFO [Executor #0 for master : executing 
HousingManagementSystem #18] 
jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService.publish Posting succeeded
31-Aug-2017 18:55:50.135 WARNING [Computer.threadPoolForRemoting [#6] for 
Channel to Maven [/usr/java/latest/bin/java, -cp, /home/ec2-
user/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-
1.11.jar:/usr/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0/boot/plexus-classworlds-
2.5.2.jar:/usr/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging, 
jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main, /usr/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0, 
/usr/apache/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-
3.10.jar, /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-
interceptor-1.11.jar, /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-
INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.11.jar, 43475] id=255] 
hudson.XmlFile.replaceIfNotAtTopLevel JENKINS-45892: reference to 
hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@7f610bfd[HousingManagementSystem] being saved but 
not at top level
31-Aug-2017 18:55:50.808 INFO [Executor #0 for master : executing 
HousingManagementSystem #18] hudson.model.Run.execute HousingManagementSystem 
#18 main build action completed: SUCCESS
31-Aug-2017 18:55:51.686 INFO [http-nio-8181-exec-16] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context 
[/HousingManagementSystem]
 31-Aug-2017 18:55:52.038 INFO [http-nio-8181-exec-16] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application 
archive [/usr/apache/apache-tomcat-
8.5.20/webapps/HousingManagementSystem.war]
31-Aug-2017 18:55:54.357 INFO [http-nio-8181-exec-16] 
org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web 
application archive [/usr/apache/apache-tomcat-
8.5.20/webapps/HousingManagementSystem.war] has finished in [2,319] ms
31-Aug-2017 18:55:54.560 INFO [Executor #0 for master : executing 
HousingManagementSystem #18] 
jenkins.plugins.slack.StandardSlackService.publish Posting succeeded
```

The only thing that shows a warning is this:

```
31-Aug-2017 18:55:50.135 WARNING [Computer.threadPoolForRemoting [#6] for 
Channel to Maven [/usr/java/latest/bin/java, -cp, /home/ec2-
user/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-agent-
1.11.jar:/usr/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0/boot/plexus-classworlds-
2.5.2.jar:/usr/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0/conf/logging, 
jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main, /usr/apache/apache-maven-3.5.0, 
/usr/apache/apache-tomcat-8.5.20/webapps/jenkins/WEB-INF/lib/remoting-
3.10.jar, /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-INF/lib/maven35-
interceptor-1.11.jar, /home/ec2-user/.jenkins/plugins/maven-plugin/WEB-
INF/lib/maven3-interceptor-commons-1.11.jar, 43475] id=255] 
hudson.XmlFile.replaceIfNotAtTopLevel JENKINS-45892: reference to 
hudson.maven.MavenModuleSet@7f610bfd[HousingManagementSystem] being saved but 
not at top level
```

I have tried previous solutions made here in stack overflow but no avail. Any thoughts?

Comment: You say you're trying to access it through `localhost`, but it's running on a remote EC2 server?

Comment: for testing i used to access it through the local host. but I deployed it in a ec2 server and i am trying to access it throught that server

Comment: And when you go to <ec2-url>/HousingManagementSystem you see a Tomcat 404 page?

Comment: yes i do, it says apache tomcat 8.5.20 at the bottom

Comment: I'd look into that "Undeploying context" line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to solve this problem with the help of a friend he told me that we were missing a method in our spring boot application class. It is the following one:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(Application.class);
}//this was the one we were missing

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}

}
```

And also added this to the dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- … -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- … -->
</dependencies>
```

This is to create a deployable war file with spring boot.

Resource: 
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file